# Jenkins build pipeline on single slave

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I have a software application that I am trying to build / test through jenkins.

In a single repo, I have a core application and several client applications

```
repo-> Core
    -> ClientApp1
    -> ClientApp2
    -> ClientApp3
```

I want to perform the following tasks each time the repo gets updated (or at some interval whatever)

1. Check out repo
2. Build each application
3. CPP Check each application
4. Valgrind
5. 6,7,8 . . . Run several Client Application tests etc

And this All needs to happen end-to-end on each test server.

I really want to have this visualized as there are ALOT of tests that happen on the end, and I would like to be able to easily see which point broke.

Currently, I have a set of jobs, that each have their up/down stream project dependencies setup and, build triggers.  I can even set up artifacts to pass inbetween.  However, I haven't figure out how to tie all the jobs to a single server.

Is there a plugin that makes this who process easier?  It seems like it would be ideal and somewhat common for many build/test setups but I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

To tie builds to a particular server, add a label to your slave, then make your build attached to a particular label. If you have multiple slaves and want to dynamically attach all the set of builds to a single node, you may be able to use the [NodeStalker](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Node+Stalker+Plugin) or maybe the [NodeLabel parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) in combination with the [Parametrized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)

It might also be possible to fiddle with the [Build Pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) to pass parameters down to jobs as well.